# Understanding array access with bitwise operators in diamond-square algorithm implementation

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, bitwise-operators

The question arose from [this article](http://www.bluh.org/code-the-diamond-square-algorithm/) which references the implementation of the [Diamond-square algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm) found in Notch's "Minicraft". The full source code is available [here](http://ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-22/?action=preview&uid=398).

I don't understand how the methods used to access and change the array of values work.

Given a specified  `width` and  `height` we initialize a 1-dimensional array of `double`s called  `values` of length  `width * height` and use the following methods to access and change the value of the point `(x,y)`:

```
public double sample(int x, int y) {
    return values[(x & (width - 1)) + (y & (height - 1)) * width];
}

public void setSample(int x, int y, double value) {
    values[(x & (width - 1)) + (y & (height - 1)) * width] = value;
}
```

I don't understand the purpose of the operations `x & (width - 1)` and `y & (height - 1)`, especially considering the fact that, to my understanding, `width` and `height` should equal [image: formula] for the algorithm to work correctly. If this is the case shouldn't the operations return `0` every time (extremes excluded), since `x < width` and `y < height`?

The source mentions that these methods have 'the side effect of allowing the terrain to wrap perfectly across the edge of the generated texture', but I don't understand how's that achieved.

Comment: it works for width and height being 2^n,   like when width is 256, width-1 would be 255, and a logic and with 255 for any value will be in range of 0 and 255 with right wraping around.

Comment: This works. I didn't realise that having the array to wrap around makes the algorithm work with a size of 2^n: the "missing" value is simply chosen from the opposite edge.